# Move Git Repo To Another Report as A Normal Folder

Tags: git

I'm currently in the process of migrating TFS projects into git whilst keeping the history which works well by using "git-tf clone" if I have a one to one mapping of a TFS project to one git repo....BUT
One team are having a clean up and would like to create one git repo and move numerous TFS folders into it.  The problem I'm having is when I do a git-tf clone each target folder is a repo:

```
c:\proj\
-------->ProjA
-------->.git
------------->Configs
------------->.git
------------->Scripts
------------->.git
```

What I'd actually like is:

```
c:\proj\
-------->ProjA
-------->.git
------------->Configs
------------->Scripts
```

Is there a way to move a repo to a plain subfolder within another repo and keep the history?

I've been searching and trying a few things but I can't seem to work it out.  My last resort would be to make the folder structure in TFS first but surely git should be able to do this.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Sorry typo in subject!!  "Report" = "Repo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First do the one-to-one conversion and you'll have a number of git-repositories.

Then create a new git repository and add the individual repositories to that one.

There are several threads on how to do that, start with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) and find a solution that fits you.

Remember, while you are trying this on your local machine there is no cost of failing. The original repositories are left intact as one-to-one copies of the TFS ones and won't be damaged by your attempts.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the quick response, this works but it doesn't seem to bring the history across with it after running git subtree, any ideas?

Comment: It should bring it. Make sure it's there in the two  (or more) original repositories.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'm not getting the point about making sure it's in 2 original repos?  There is only 1 repo with the comments which I'm trying to move into a subfolder of another project so there wouldn't be more than 2....